# How to change the origin/pivot point of a parent of many objects

Tags: transforms

I have a houseplant object and pot object both as children to an empty parent object, and I'm trying to change the pivot of the parent to be the center of the bottom of the pot.  If I select the child components separately I can set this pivot by moving the 3D cursor in place and using Set Origin.  However, as soon as I select the parent, the pivot is still in a random location and the Set Origin button disappears.  Is there an easier way to deal with this? Thanks

Comment: Trying to reproduce this, no problems, set the cursor at the bottom of the pot, select both objects and run origin to 3d cursor, it works as expected. Make sure your pivot point is set to _bounding box center_.